# How to remove a data from main memory/RAM

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

Is there any way to remove a specific data from the main memory in Linux ? So that is has to bring again that data from the hard-disk

Comment: This is not a question about code

Comment: What do You mean by "specific data"? In case of C or whatever lower level language, You can always fill specific parts of memory with zeroes before `free`'ing it. Also, You could patch Linux kernel, or specifically, memory manager to do it for You. I guess.

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: linux provide functionality to flush swap memory data. command [#]sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;                 for specific memory area you may have to write code.

Comment: Those falsely complaining that this is off topic need to ask themselves in what context other than programming or intimate knowledge of a program the goal would have meaning - ie, where else would you know specifically where specific data was located in memory?  By hoping someone had mmap()'d it so you could see that in /proc?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than removing a specific piece of data, this will remove all from the linux cache. (I am assuming this is what you mean when you want linux to reload a file from the hard disk into main memory).

```
sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

Link: [How to clear memory cache on linux](http://www.linuxtoday.com/upload/how-to-clear-memory-cache-on-linux-130703011018.html)

Also, my apologies to [Mohit M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156956/mohit-m) as he answered this in the comment section before me.

Answer (score -1):

You could always change your app to use O_DIRECT flag which bypasses the page cache and fetches file from diskc for a specific read call. Now it may not work in all cases (especially in case of stacked block devices etc) in which case you should stick to drop_caches like other before me explained.

Comment: why the -1 ? No comment ?